# Java Replacement for certain LINQ methods

Tags: java, linq

I have some C# `List<MyCustomType<T>> where T : ICloneable` on which the following extension methods are applied:

- `Where(x => x.Start > Start && x.End < End).ToList()`
- `OrderBy(x => x.Start).ToList()`
- `Select(x => x.Clone()).ToList()`
- `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Start == Start)` (Default means `null`)
- `WhereMin(x => x.Start).ToList()` / `WhereMax(x => x.Start).ToList()`

I have to convert the code into Java; everything else should be straightforward, but I am trying not to replace all these LINQ calls with simple loops.

Is there a simpler way to replace any, if not all, of these functions?

And which list should I use, is an `ArrayList` okay or is there anything else I should prefer?

Comment: Can you use Java 8, or not?  And yes, `ArrayList` is basically always the answer.

Comment: Recently java introduced streams https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html They are far from being as elegant as LINQ, but it is the closest you will get in brevity and readability.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Is a binary compiled with JDK 8 compatible to older JRE? Otherwise, I can't use Java 8.

Comment: It's not, and if you can't use Java 8, then you're stuck with for loops.

Comment: It's only compatible when executed with a java 8 runtime. Pre Java 8: you got to for-each loop the arrays and do everything manually.

Comment: I just found `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`, this *could* at least save me the implementation of my own sort function. Not sure yet, though...